# *.xlsm is Locked for editing by User after deploying in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have opened excel file on button click from specific folder location in the server from iis, the file is being opened by saving file instance in temp folder. I have a save button in excel with macros which will save the opened file to another folder.But I am unable to save the file to another folder from excel(Is this because that file is opening in the temp).The error I am getting is ,it is locked by the Login User.

Comment: well.. your "user" is still having the file open. save and close the file and then move it to the new folder

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it a little clearer what you are trying to achieve? It's a little hard to follow at the moment.